# Proving $s_n^k \rightarrow s^k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Given $s_n \rightarrow s$ where $s_n$ in a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, I want to prove that $s_n^k \rightarrow s^k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know by definition that a sequence converges if $\exists p \in X$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n>N$, $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$.

Here's my rough try at a proof I'm working on:

By a theorem, if $s_n^k \rightarrow s^k$ and if $s_n \rightarrow s$, then $s_n^k 
\cdot s_n \rightarrow s^{(k+1)}$. I'm thinking of proving this by induction.

So for the base case we want to show:

$s_n \cdot s_n = s_n^2 \rightarrow s^2$.

It follows that to prove convergence I need to find an upper bound for $|s_n^2 - s_n|$. Since I know that $s_n$ converges, it must have an upper bound $M \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $|s_n| < M$. And so $\forall n > N, |s_n^2 - s_n| < \epsilon \backslash M$.

Now it's time to prove the case using the inductive hypothesis.

Assume $s_n^{k+1} \rightarrow s^{k+1}$ is true. Then prove $s_n^{(k+2)} \rightarrow s^{k+2}$ is true. Well, rewriting this gives $s_n^{k+1}s_n \rightarrow s^{k+1}s$. From the theorem, we know that this converges because $s^{k+1}$ converges and so does $s_n$. QED.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
|s_n^k - s^k| =|s_n-s|\left|\sum^{k-1}_{\ell=0} s_n^{k-1-\ell}s^\ell \right|\leq |s_n-s|\sum^{k-1}_{\ell=0} |s_n|^{k-1-\ell}|s|^\ell .
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still not really seeing how this would help. I'm assuming I have to find $\epsilon$ such that $|s_n-s|\sum^{k-1}_{\ell=0} |s_n|^{k-1-\ell}|s|^\ell$ $< \epsilon$?

Comment: Here's another hint: Since $s_n\rightarrow s$, then there exists $N$ such that $|s_n|\leq |s|+1$ for all  $n>N$ which means 
\begin{align}
\sum^{k-1}_{\ell=0}|s_n|^{k-1-\ell}|s|^\ell \leq  k(|s|+1|)^{k-1}
\end{align}
which is just a big constant.